# PHP - How to handle method calls

Tags: php

Which is the better way to handle the following case? I've been wondering about this for a while and figured I'd ask.

Define a variable?

```
$getItems = $itemTools->getItems($item_id);

if($getItems)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Or

```
if($itemTools->getItems($item_id))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: First one looks cleaner for me

Comment: If you need to do anything with the value, then store it in a variable so you don't need to re-fetch it.  If you don't need to do anything with the value, then `getItems` seems like a misnomer.  `hasItems` would probably be more appropriate.  The `if` block should read like the logical condition being checked.

Comment: So if I define a variable and then check if that variable is true it will re-fetch? Meaning it will do the query twice? Or it doesn't query when defining the variable?

Comment: `if($getItems = $itemTools->getItems($item_id))` compromise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it would depend on what you were doing after/within the if branch. If your plan is doing something with the returned data then it makes sense to me storing the results in a var. Otherwise it doesn't.

Looking at the function name I'm assuming it is not a simple check but a function returning 'usable' data so probably you will use this data and you actually need the var.

Unless you are doing this in the global scope, if you are doing this within some method then php will release the memory used by this var once the method ends.

What about doing another (and quick) method named 'hasResults($itemId)' returning a boolean?

Just wondering

Comment: Yes ... in my question I gave an example that actually returns data which is used.

Comment: Ok. Then you must store that var otherwise you will be forced to call the method again.